# Laravel centrally manage user roles/access levels

Tags: security, laravel, authentication

**How can I centrally manage roles/user access in Laravel?**

If I have 2 applications, how can I store the fact that a user may be a basic user in 1 application and a power user or admin in another?

Comment: welcome , first read how to ask question in Stackoverflow carefully , second : you can use packages like https://github.com/romanbican/roles to learn how to do that

Comment: Great, but how will that centrally manage access levels across multiple applications?

Answer (score 0):

So, I did this with a separate mySQL database.

I add this to mu User class `protected $connection = 'mysqlUserDB';` which specifies that it should connect to a different database, which contains my roles and permissions.

I have this: `'admin_role' => 'process_loss_admin',` In my application.php.

I can then test if the logged in user is an Administrator:

`if ($user->hasRole(config('application.admin_role'))) {`

Simple